# How to enable intellisense for tensorflow in vs code

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, intellisense

i have a problem with tensorflow that doesn't work in my visual studio code and when i install it given me that "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow " so anyone know how to slov this problem?

i try to download it from tensorflow wepsite

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From your problem description, it seems that you are not using pip to install the Python package.

You can use `pip install tensorflow` command in your terminal to install the tensorflow package.